# Overloading method of visual component restricts access to private members

Tags: delphi, overloading, delphi-xe2

I'm using a visual component [`TJvListView`](http://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/blob/9d1976ea193e14b54a725819a9b12bb102be71e2/jvcl/run/JvListView.pas) from the JEDI JVCL library. Here are the relevant declarations of this component class:

```
TJvListView = class(TJvExListView)
private
  FOnSaveProgress: TJvOnProgress;
public
  procedure SaveToStrings(Strings: TStrings; Separator: Char);
```

What I'm trying to do is replace the `SaveToStrings()` method with my own modified definition. I tried to do this using the ["interposer" class way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14783549/797744):

```
uses
  JvListView
type
  TJvListView = class(JvListView.TJvListView)
  public
    procedure SaveToStrings(Strings: TStrings; Separator: Char);
  end;

  TfrmFaultMemView = class(TForm)
    lvFMEs: TJvListView;
  end;

procedure TJvListView.SaveToStrings(Strings: TStrings; Separator: Char);
begin
  if Assigned(Self.FOnSaveProgress) then  // COMPILER ERROR HERE
  begin
  end;
end;
```

The original method depends on accessing some private members of the class, and I have to keep that code in my modified definition.

However, when I try to compile this it gives me an error:

> E2361 Cannot access private symbol TJvListView.FOnSaveProgress

I'm tryin to re-define a public method, but it's unavoidable that they must access private members/methods. Given that, how can I overload that method with my own definition?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043501/ for another dupe, and I'm sure there are more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `private` field `FOnSaveProgress` use `published` property `OnSaveProgress`

When you extend class you can only access it's `protected`, `public` or `published` members. `Private` members are, well, private and cannot be accessed not even from extending class. The only place where you can access `private` members from other class is if both classes are in same unit and members are not marked as `strict private`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure I can use that property; I'm trying to keep the code as close to the functionality of the original, and the [original](https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/blob/9d1976ea193e14b54a725819a9b12bb102be71e2/jvcl/run/JvListView.pas#L1612) accesses that private member directly.

Comment: Using property or field in this case is the same.

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like you're right :) I appreciate the help